# Best Step by Step Approach for Unity

Tags: unity

I'm planning to start learning Unity 3D with a friend of mine. I would like to know if there will be a good step by step process of which I should start learning. I never had any background in game development. But have a good foundation of `C#`, any guide to which I should start would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is not on topic: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A good place to start is the Unity homepage, more specifically the Learn/Tutorials section. There is a topic called "Interface & Essentials", where you learn the basics of the Unity editor. This could be a good starting point. There are also tutorials where you create a simple game from scratch, as well as tutorials on specific topics like 2D game creation. Just look for yourself:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials